# Error due to parsing JSON string response in android

Tags: java, android, json, video, youtube

I am trying to create an app for a youtube channel and want to display the list of videos in a recyclerview. I am using YoutubeData API v3 for this. I get a JSON string response in return for my query and I am parsing it manually.

I created a class called Video to store information about a video in an object and then add it to an ArrayList to pass to recyclerview adapter. Initially it worked fine but as the number of details I wanted to pass to Video object increased, the recyclerview stopped working. It just shows the latest two videos and the rest are not displayed.

As soon as I pass videoId to the adapter the recycler view stops working. I tried parsing json on a separate thread using AsyncTask but it did not work. I am stuck in this error for a long time and can't figure out a reason. Please help !!

Here is my code :

MainActivity.java :

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    URL url = null;
    String resultString = null;
    RecyclerView rv;
    VideoAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Video> titles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_display);
        url = NetworkUtils.buildUrlFromUsername(Config.FOR_USERNAME);
        Log.i("ayusch", "url = " + url);
        new YoutubeQueryTask().execute(url);
        Log.i("ayusch", "After task");

    }

    public void formatJSON(String resultString) {
        new JSONParseTask().execute(resultString);
    }

    public class YoutubeQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
            URL builtUrl = params[0];
            resultString = "no result";
            try {
                resultString = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromUrl(builtUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return resultString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            formatJSON(s);

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            adapter = new VideoAdapter(titles);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }


    public class  JSONParseTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONObject itemsObj, thumbnailsObject, defaultObject, obj, snippetObj;
            ArrayList<Video> videoTitles = new ArrayList<>();
            String title, thumbnailUrl, description, videoId;
            try {
                itemsObj = new JSONObject(resultString);
                JSONArray itemsArray = itemsObj.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {

                    obj = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    snippetObj = obj.getJSONObject("snippet");

                    title = snippetObj.getString("title");
                    thumbnailsObject = snippetObj.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                    defaultObject = thumbnailsObject.getJSONObject("default");
                    thumbnailUrl = defaultObject.getString("url");
                    description = snippetObj.getString("description");
                    videoId = (obj.getJSONObject("id")).getString("videoId");
                    videoTitles.add(new Video(title, thumbnailUrl, description,videoId));
                    Log.i("ayusch", "length of array = " + i);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           titles=videoTitles;
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

VideoAdapter.java :

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.CustomHolder> {

    private int maxNumItems = 25;
    ArrayList<Video> titles;

    public VideoAdapter(ArrayList<Video> titles) {
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        CustomHolder holder = new CustomHolder(root, parent.getContext());
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_title.setText((titles.get(position).title));
        String url = titles.get(position).thumbnailUrl;
        Picasso.with(holder.tv_title.getContext()).load(url).into(holder.iv_thumbnail);
        holder.tv_description.setText((titles.get(position)).description);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    public class CustomHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_title,tv_description;
        ImageView iv_thumbnail;
        Context c;

        public CustomHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_video_title);
            iv_thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_video_thumbnail);
            tv_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_video_description);
            c = context;
        }


    }
}
```

Video.java :

```
public class Video {
    String title;
    String thumbnailUrl;
    String description;
    String videoId;

    Video(String vidTitle, String url, String desc, String vidId) {
        title = vidTitle;
        thumbnailUrl = url;
        description = desc;
        videoId = vidId;
    }
}
```

[image: Error ( just two videos displayed )]

[image: Without videoId being passed. It should look like this.]

Also please feel free to suggest any code improvements for performance. I am still in my learning phase and want to write good performance code and this app takes a while to load json response in recyclerview.

Comment: Any errors in logcat?

Comment: It says no adapter attached, skipping layout....
But two items are displaying though.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Do `titles` ArrayList `initialization` and set RecyclerView `adapter` from `onCreate()` method.

**2.** Clear `titles` list from `JSONParseTask` for every data fetch operation.

**3.** Add `Video` object to list `titles` instead of `videoTitles`.

**4.** Call  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update `RecyclerView` after adding each item to `titles` list.

**Update your `MainActivity` as below:**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    URL url = null;
    String resultString = null;
    RecyclerView rv;
    VideoAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Video> titles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_display);
        url = NetworkUtils.buildUrlFromUsername(Config.FOR_USERNAME);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        titles = new ArrayList<Video>();
        adapter = new VideoAdapter(titles);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.i("ayusch", "url = " + url);
        new YoutubeQueryTask().execute(url);
        Log.i("ayusch", "After task");
    }

    public void formatJSON(String resultString) {
        new JSONParseTask().execute(resultString);
    }

    public class YoutubeQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
            URL builtUrl = params[0];
            resultString = "no result";
            try {
                resultString = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromUrl(builtUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return resultString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            formatJSON(s);
        }
    }

    public class  JSONParseTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONObject itemsObj, thumbnailsObject, defaultObject, obj, snippetObj;

            String title, thumbnailUrl, description, videoId;
            try {
                itemsObj = new JSONObject(resultString);
                JSONArray itemsArray = itemsObj.getJSONArray("items");

                // Required to clear list
                if (itemsArray.length() > 0)
                    titles.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {

                    obj = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    snippetObj = obj.getJSONObject("snippet");

                    title = snippetObj.getString("title");
                    thumbnailsObject = snippetObj.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                    defaultObject = thumbnailsObject.getJSONObject("default");
                    thumbnailUrl = defaultObject.getString("url");
                    description = snippetObj.getString("description");
                    videoId = (obj.getJSONObject("id")).getString("videoId");

                    // Add to list
                    titles.add(new Video(title, thumbnailUrl, description,videoId));

                    // Update RecyclerView
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Log.i("ayusch", "length of array = " + i);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: didn't work :(   
now it's not displaying even the two items.....only when I try to scroll , the first item is displayed and that too only title. Logcat is empty.

Comment: try removing if (itemsArray.length() > 0)
                    titles.clear();

Comment: not working.....screen is blank...Also when I put a log statement in for loop I found that the loop is running only 2 times

Comment: what is the length of your itemsArray?

Comment: itemsArray length is 25

Comment: The main problem is the loop. The loop is running only 2 times and I can't figure out a reason why. Even if I hardcode the value of i to 25 still the loop runs only twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify your code for simple REST calls. You can use this library [Android RESTAdapter](https://forkachild.github.io/Android-RESTAdapter/)

It is extremely trivial to use and reduces code by a lot.